# Is it possbile to add/update two different children nodes on android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On my firebase database

[image]

Is it possible to add months,name,pay on child **Transactions** while also updating the data on DATE at child **Users**?

If so how? If not what are the alternatives ways so that when I add a new child at transactions  i can update the date on my users when doing so?

Comment: Yes you can use [multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

Comment: Is there any other way to update at multiple nodes without using hashMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Firebase comes with a feature that allow you perform simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree with a single call. Simultaneous updates made this way are `atomic`: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/Accounts/Transactions/" + transactionKey, transactionMap);
childUpdates.put("/Users/" + userId + "/", userMap);
rootRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: Can I ask for some ideas or ways so that I can get the userID of the user that I want to update the data into? ex. I can probably get the unique key of each of the transactions but I'm at lost when getting the unique key or userId of the Users that I want to update

Comment: Because I see that you are using authentication, to get the userId please use the following line of code: `String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();`

Comment: Hmm what if I I have to get the userid of a user I'm not  logged into?

Comment: In that case, you need to find that user based on another property rather then than the `uid`, let's say the email address, get the `userId`, make the updade, right?

Comment: Oh right!!! aaa so hmm how can I get the unique email address per user? hmm

Comment: You need to have it the first place because you are using it to find the `uid` of the user. Once you have found the user based on the email address, you can get the `userId`. How can you find a user if don't either the `uid` or either the `email address`? You cannot! Because you don't even know what you are searching for. Right?

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for clarifying my confusions sir